# OpenERP - Exporting Bill of Materials Structure data to Excel

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to export Bill of Materials (BOM) Structure data to Excel or PDF.

I am using Odoo v8 on Ubuntu.

I have also installed "web_export_view" and "web_printscreen_zb" modules and none of them displays export buttons on "Bill of Materials Structure" page. It appears that both modules will display buttons only if the active view is "list" view and not "tree" view. For "Bill of Materials Structure" page active view is "tree" view, and the data is displayed in parent, child hierarchical fashion.

The question is how to export to Excel or PDF the "Bill of Materials Structure" page?

Comment: I am using the web_export_view module to export everything in tree view to excel. You can get the module here: https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/7.0/web_export_view/                        Hope it helps

Comment: @Ankita Do you know, by any chance, how to make the "Export Current View" button always visible at the top of the page on which tree view is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

When you're signed in as an admin you're always able to export.

1. Go to the desired model for your export in tree view.
2. Select the fields you want to export
3. Click the dropdown "More" (if your Odoo is set to english)
4. Hit export
5. Select export all data instead of export import compatible data
6. Select Excel instead of csv
7. Select the fields you want to export
8. Click export to file

This should get you your export file